# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, api, dom, promise, typeerror

** I have a problem when I try to get data back from database.
How to fix this bug, please ? **

```
    const currentEl_one = document.getElementById('currency-one'); 
    const amountEl_one = document.getElementById('amount-one'); 
    const currentEl_two = document.getElementById('currency-two'); 
    const amountEl_two = document.getElementById('amount-two');  


const rateEl = document.getElementById('rate');
```

**// Fetch exchange rates and update the DOM**

```
const calculate() => {
    const currency_one = currentEl_one.value; 
    const currency_two = currentEl_two.value; 

    fetch(`https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest/${currency_one}`) 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const rate = data.rates[currency_two]; 
        rateEl.innerHTML = `1 ${currency_one} = ${rate} ${currency_two}`; 
        amountEl_two.value = (amountEl_one.value * rate).toFixed(2);
    });
}
```

**// Event Listener**

```
currentEl_one.addEventListener('change', calculate); 
amountEl_one.addEventListener('input', calculate); 
currentEl_two.addEventListener('change', calculate); 
amountEl_two.addEventListener('input', calculate);  

swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const temp = currentEl_one.value; 
    currentEl_one.value = currentEl_two.value; 
    currentEl_two.value = temp; 
    calculate();
})
calculate();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Could you provide the entire Error stack trace